# How to list types/values from a TS interface/type?

Tags: typescript, interface

There is a way to list valid values from a interface/type? Given:

```js
interface IFoo {
    foo1: "a" | "b" | "c";
    foo2: string;
    foo3: "foo" | number;
}
```

A possible response:

```js
{
    foo1: ["a", "b", "c"],
    foo2: String,
    foo3: ["foo", Number],
}
```

I don't think this is possible using only TS, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.

Types only exist at compile time, and are gone when your code is running. So there is nothing to build that object from.

In fact, your example output is not assignable to your interface. What if the type was `Array<"a" | "b" | "c">`? Then what the output be?

And with more complex types where values are instances of classes or functions or generics it would be impossible for the compiler to guess what you really want.

You simply can't express the richness of a type in a single value.

---

You can go the other way, though:

```
const foo = {
    foo1: ["a", "b", "c"],
    foo2: 'd',
    foo3: ["foo", 123],
} as const

type IFoo = typeof foo
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeAoG36IIwBcMA2gEQCGpANDKQEbW3CkC6VWOCIATEQOQATPuxy4QAZiJkujPN3FsMAXxjkIMUJCgYMUAJ4AHAKYwAkgDFEKGPuMg4YoA)